# Why was my algorithm for this interview a sub-optimal approach?

Tags: python, algorithm, subset-sum

> Given a list of integers, `l = [1,5,3,2,6]` and a target `t = 6`, return true if the list contains two distinct integers that sum to the target

I was given this question on a technical Python interview that caused me not to pass. My answer was:

```
def two_Sum(l, target):
  for num in l:
    for secondNum in l:
      if num != secondNum:
        if num + secondNum == target:
          return True
```

The feedback I was given was that my solution was "not optimal".  Please help me to understand why this was not the optimal solution and explain in detail what would be optimal for this case!

Comment: can you have repeated elements in the list?

Comment: the link you provided looks to find *ALL* unique pairs whereas my question only looks to find one and return True (might still be the same general concept but im new to these types of algorithms so im not completely sure)

Comment: @AndrewDeNike It is the exact same concept.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution has a nested loop iterating the list, which means it's *O(n^2)* time complexity - and *O(1)* space, since you don't need to store any data during the iteration.

Reducing to *O(n)* time complexity is possible like this, coming at the cost of increasing to O(n) space complexity:

```
def two_sum(l, target):
    s = set(l)
    for n in l:
        delta = target - n
        if delta != n and delta in s:
            return True
    return False
```

As a slight improvement, you can even avoid to traverse the entire list, but it's still *O(n)*:

```
def two_sum(l, target):
    seen = set()
    for n in l:
        delta = target - n
        if delta != n and delta in seen:
            return True
        seen.add(n)
    return False
```

Comment: Not sure you you were DVed but I guess you could add a bit about space complexity tradeoffs?

Comment: @miradulo I added some details about the space complexity tradeoff.

Comment: Looks like the most complete answer to me :)

Comment: @wim would you say that O(n^2) time complexity/O(1) space is _less optimal_ than O(n) time complexity/O(1) space ?  trying to wrap my head around the tiers and hierarchy of O notation!

Comment: Yes, polynomial complexity is less optimal than linear complexity.

Comment: @wim lastly, in relation to my posted solution, are the 's=set(l)' and 'seen = set()' what make your two respective solutions become O(n) ?

Comment: Yes.  Membership test on set is O(1) amortized.

Answer (score 1):

you can start by having two pointers (start,end), start will point to start of the list and end will point to end of list, then add them and see if it equals to your target, if equals then print or add to result.

if sum is greater then your target that means decrease your end pointer by 1 and if it's equal to or smaller than your target then increase your start pointer.

```
def two_Sum(l,target):
    start=0
    end=len(l)-1
    while start!=end:
        pair_sum=l[start]+l[end]
        if pair_sum==target:
            print l[start],l[end]

        if pair_sum <= target:
            start=start+1

        if pair_sum > target:
            end = end-1


l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


two_Sum(l,9)
```

Comment: This only works for a sorted list, which isn't guaranteed in the question - you might want to adjust accordingly.

Comment: yup we need to sort the list first, still complexity would be o(NlogN), depends on sorting algorithm

Answer (score 0):

This will only go once through your list:

```
def two_sum(l, t):
  s = set(l)
  for n in s:
    if t-n in s:
      if n != t-n:
        return True
  return False
```

Comment: No, it won't. This is extremely inefficient.

Comment: That's O(n**2), just like the OP's solution.

Comment: This doesn't look that much different from wim answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to hash T-I[i] for each i and check each element as you see it

```
def sum2(I,T):
   h = {}
   for itm in I:
      if itm in h:
          return True
      h[T-itm] = 1
   return False
```

Comment: Maybe `set` instead of `dict` would be more appropriate semantically.

Comment: This one also gives incorrect results for some of the edge cases

Comment: @wim - Care to share?

Comment: @wim I dont see the point in saying that this code fails for some edge cases, but don't even share what they are?

Comment: See the line `if num != secondNum` in OP code ... this one didn't address the requirement to find two *distinct* integers.

Comment: @wim - The way this problem is usually given is distinct is used in the sense of repeating a single element (I=[4], T=8 returns false) rather than  adding two of the same number (I=[4,4], T=8 returns false)

Comment: Naturally, but then the problem must be specified like "two distinct elements" or "two different indices" and not "two distinct integers".

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is `O(n²)`, as you do a nested iteration of the whole list.

A simple solution with time complexity `n log(n)` would be:

- sort your list
- iterate doing a binary search for the complementary to `target`

Supposing you have binary search implemented in function `bs(item, sorted_list)`:

```
def two_Sum(l, target):
    l_sorted = sorted(l)  # n log(n)
    return any(bs(target - x, l_sorted) for x in l_sorted)  # n log(n)
```

You can also do some other optimisation like stop iterating if you reach `target/2`.

Caveat: I don't garantee nor really believe this is *the* optimal solution, but rather intended to show you a better one and give insight to your improving your own.